# How to obtain this in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, image

I have a bunch of image tags in my HTML page. I want to take count of those images which have the src in it somewhere called warning.png. How to match this pattern and get the count. How to get in jQuery?

```
<img src="/images/warning.png?1284446116" alt="Warning">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('img[src*="warning.png"]')
```

Comment: but it is not working.. look at my src.. it has warning.png somewhere in it.. not only that..

Comment: And of course...if you want the count, just add a .length to the end of it, or .size()